# Dropdown list not showing appropriate data

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, dropdownbox

I have following code All I want is to show `dropdown` with default selected as `--Select--` But its showing it incorrectly, What am I doing wrong??

```
Dim i As Integer
For i = 2008 To 2100
   ddlYear.Items.Add(i.ToString())
Next i
ddlYear.Items.FindByValue(System.DateTime.Now.Year.ToString()).Selected = True
ddlYear.Items.Insert(0, New ListItem("--Select--", 1))
```

See picture attached. It should set default to `"--Select--` also It is appearing twice, it should not[image]

Comment: exchange the position of last two code lines...

Comment: Doesnt work. Check edited post

Comment: You are also setting 2015 selected in your second last line...

Comment: I rectified that. But its showing select twice

Comment: Why is it showing "--Select--" Twice?

Comment: I did the same, but it is not showing twice the text "--Select--"

Comment: This code will add `--Select--` only once and will select `2015` as selected item. There might be some other code somewhere that is adding the other `--Select--`. You need to check that.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

```
Dim i As Integer

ddlYear.Items.Add("--Select--")
For i = 2008 To 2100
    ddlYear.Items.Add(i.ToString())
Next i

ddlYear.SelectedIndex = 0
```